# Get Images in full screen inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager, scrollview, gallery

I would like to create a gallery app, in which there may be different sized images, into a ViewPager just like the default Android gallery app does.
My issue is that I can't manage to center+resize my images so that they fit perfectly inside the screen (I often get a vertical scrolling)

My xml code is very basic : 
Activity Slider

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_display"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</ScrollView>
```

edit : posted code on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Zd91aR30)

Answer (score 3):

Use this in `<ImageView>` `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: sadly it doesn't work. I tried with various scaleType but I still can scroll vertically for mysterious raisons

Comment: edited my question, but I mostly followed a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have scrolling because of the viewpager's height set to match_parent.

Try, just to see :

layout_height="400dp"

and

ScaleType = "CenterCrop"

I have no solution on how to display the height dynamically for the viewPager, since the WRAP_CONTENT value doesn't work on this component.